# Primefaces how prevent call backing bean when rendered is false

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2

We are working with Primefaces 5.3 atm. There are a few page which we want our user to verify their info first before display page content (re-enter their password for example). So we show the confirm dialog first and set the rendered attribute for page content to false. After our user click confirm button on the dialog, we hide the dialog, change the rendered value to true and update the page so the page content can be display.

But even though the rendered attribute is false, the backing bean still got call. Our PostConstruct method was executed before our user confirm which result in some exception ( Like trying to display a dialog but since rendered is false, javascript PF result in undefined ).

So is there a way to completely prevent backing bean got call when rendered attribute is false? Or is there another way beside using rendered ?

===================================================

UPDATE :
We try to use if else to add the content

```
<p:outputPanel id="mainPanel">
    <c:if test="#{bean.confirmed eq true}">
        <div id="layout-portlets-cover" class="fontRegular">
            <ui:insert name="content"></ui:insert>
        </div>
    </c:if>
</p:outputPanel>
```

This way it did not call backing bean when confirmed is true, but when we changed value to false, backing bean got call but no html generated for main content ( blank page ).
Anyone have any ideal how to fix this problem ?

===================================================

UPDATE 2 :
It seem when we use c:if to display page content, the postConstruct run before the pageContent got generated (Since it generated through update instead of normal load page). So some of our javascript got mess up since component doesnt exist yet which cause exception and stop the update script. That why we got blank page.
Is there a way to make it work like normal instead of changing code, moving the script from postConstruct to another place?

===================================================

UPDATE 3 :
If we use update attribute in our commandButton, then the page content return when the confirm request done. This way we will have everything ready for the script return from the PostConstruct method. But it result in our function to get page attribute return null.

```
uiComponent.getAttributes().get(key);
```

If we put update in another remoteCommand and call it on onComplete of the confirm request then it error like in UPDATE 2.
So either way will result in some error for our current code.
Anyway to get page attribute in the first way?